# Object appears in Object mode but not in Render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Learning Blender 2.8. Frosting with sprinkles Object appears in object mode but not in render. Any help would be appreciated.

Another note is that when I toggle to edit mode on the mug or plate I can see the object in edit mode. But when I toggle to edit mode on frosting with sprinkles. I doesn't show up in edit mode.

[image: Object]
[image: Render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Outliner*, click on the key icon to display the *Render* option (camera icon) and make sure the option is enabled for your object.

[image]

Second solution: if this surface is an emitter, make sure you've enabled the *Show Emitter* option in the *Particles* panel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No luck there, unfortunately.

Comment: then please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6432/

Comment: ok I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you moonboots, the show emitter option solved my problem. Thanks so much, highly appreciated!