# Object disppear when i change to the render cycle view

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am new in blender. I am trying to change it to cycles render but the object I build just disappears! And I an see them when I change it to edit mode. Can anyone help?

Comment: What Blender version do you use?

Comment: Its through steam so the latest one 2.81

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda tough to answer that. Have you checked in the outliner if the object is visible for rendering? Look at this:
[Object appears in Object mode but not in Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149607/object-appears-in-object-mode-but-not-in-render)

Comment: I dont know how but I fixed it after 5 hours