# Objects are missing and hidden objects appear when rendering(Blender 2.81a)

Tags: rendering

[image]

⬆️ like that

there are some answer under other similar question said need to select all objects in object mode and click [M] to [Clear all restrict render], but when i click [M] , the mouse just change into the select circle, I don't know how to clear all restrict render.
hope someone can help me with the problem. 
thank you guys.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). You probably need to check *Show Emitter* in your particle settings https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/149607/78972

Comment: Thank you very much Jachym Michal! it's very helpful!